# Adding Beanshell post processor in testplan

Tags: jmeter

I need to compare results from two apis which I am running in two threads.I am wondering if I can add a beanshell post processor in the test plan and refer to the elements in the threads to generate a report. Can this be done?

Or is it possible to include a variable from my beanshell postprocessor script to Summary report?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) to store the responses into JMeter Variables, regular expression which matches the full response looks like

   ```
   (?s)(^.*)
   ```

   You can compare 2 JMeter Variables or response with a variable using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion). See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for details.
2. For storing any JMeter Variable in .jtl results file just declare it using 
   [sample_variables property](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) in *user.properties* file like:

   ```
   sample_variables=foo
   ```

   Given the above property set `${foo}` variable value will be added to .jtl results file as the last column. See

Comment: Sorry I am not so clear about the second one. This is my beanshell script and I want "Totalfilteredresult" in the summary report. I understand how to ser the property in the property file, but I am not sure how to refer it.

Comment: import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
Totalfilteredresult = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("totalfilteredresult"));
String city = vars.get("city");
log.info("City " + city +" has "+Totalfilteredresult+" Hotels");
f = new FileOutputStream("../../Reports/25CitiesHotelOffers.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println(city +","+Totalfilteredresult+" Offers");
p.close();
f.close();